# How to find position of a web element in relation to another web element?

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I have to assert the presence of a web element with its position. To be more clear I have a web element X and another web element Y. Now I have to assert that after clicking a button I can see X sitting above Y. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should get the two elements‘ positions in the document and subtract the position value of X from the value of Y. If that value is positive, you know that X is sitting farther up than Y.

#### Getting the position

Use

```
boxPositionOfX = getElementById(“myX”).getBoundingClientRect();
boxPositionOfY = getElementById(“myY”).getBoundingClientRect();
```

This returns an object containing all four position values: `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`, relative to the viewport. You do not need to convert the viewport positions to the document positions, since the document offset you'd have to add is the same for both elements and will be cut in the subtraction.

#### Comparing positions

Now subtract their positions:

```
positionDifference = boxPositionOfY.top - boxPositionOfX.top;
```

If the `positionDifference` is greater than 0, X’s top border lies above Y’s top border.

If you want to make sure the elements do not overlap, use this:

```
If ( (boxPositionOfY.top - boxPositionOfX.bottom) >= 0) {
    alert("X is above Y. They do not overlap.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! the suggestion looks awesome. I am just going to try it and will inform :)